# Get user dimensions in Parse using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

One of the columns in my User class is their passport number (called "passport").
How can I query all their passport numbers for a specific group of users saved in an group (team) using javascript if I have them in an array?

This is my best try so far:

```js
var team = [Paul, Ringo, George, John]
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", team[i])
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    alert(results.get('passport'));
    },
    error: function(error) {
      // handle error   
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `containedIn` in order to get something based on an array:

```
var team = ["Paul", "Ringo", "George", "John"];
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.containedIn("username", team);
var passports = [];
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        results.map(function(result){
            //just an example, handle results however you need
            passports.push(result.get("passport"));
            if(passports.length == results.length){
                console.log(passports);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // handle error   
    }
});
```

Edit: You can read up more about querying using parse here:

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-query-constraints